# loading Data of 100 users using angularJS along with DOM modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, mousedown

I have a data of 100 users and their info along with that i got their images. It is obvious that it will slow down. So I was first getting all the Info of users and then tried getting the images of users. It looks like this is also delayed. so my plan is to implement like facebook or twitter once we came end to the info of 10 users it should load other 10 users. 
I think with `mousedown` we can achieve it.
My current code looks like this.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in userss">
    <img ng-src="www.xxx.com/{{user.id}}.jpg" class="circle" altSrc="www.xxx.com/default.jpg" onerror="this.src = $(this).attr('altSrc')" />
    <span class="title">{{user.fullname }}</span>
</li>
```

Thank you, I think we can do it by adding jQuery but I don't have any idea of jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution for infinte scroll implemented in jquery.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       for(var x= z*10; x < (z+1)*10,user> x ;x++ ){
            newList.push(users[x]);
       }
          $scope.users = newList;
          $scope.$apply();         
   }
});
```

here i have limited 10 users

Answer (score 1):

Your performance should be better with `<li ng-repeat="user in users track by user.id">`

Reference: http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/

Comment: this looks like that we can use track by to refresh the whole page.

Comment: The UI-Bootstrap package also has a pagination component, you can see it in work here: http://plnkr.co/edit/eheFSh?p=info

Comment: no i'm using it for smart phones so it would be better if that worked like facebook or twitter. where they do loading once reached the end of page.

Comment: Then use one of the infinite scrollers like this one: https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll, demo: http://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html

Comment: this is really good directive example. can't we complete this by using jQuery. Actually i was looking to learn jQuery

Comment: Sure why not. Accept answer, upvote and ask as a jQuery question.

Comment: jQuery is largely superfluous, if not actively harmful, in Angular.

Comment: @DanielBeck components (or directives) can link the two worlds (you know, of course), without problems. But, ok, some jQuery plugins can harm, but you can switch the bad plugin for other better, only updating the component bind.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I couldn't possibly disagree more. Angular's great, jQuery's great too, but they're basically opposite approaches to working with the DOM.  Two great tastes best enjoyed separately.

Comment: how do you do if i required of scroll up also..to divide the DOM with 10 list at a time....as the example shown by @JohannesJander is for scroll down. If you are trying to implement this for phones list will load with laggy...you will get it if you have worked with list in android phones to upload data.https://developersday.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/scrollable-divs-rendering-issues-with-css-overflow-auto-or-scroll-iosandroid/     and    https://developersday.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/scrollable-divs-rendering-issues-with-css-overflow-auto-or-scroll-iosandroid/

Comment: @DanielBeck really sorry for long message... is it possible to implement without using JQuery window object.I don't think there is no directive which is built in for my requirement

Comment: @santhosh make up your mind already. Do you want it implemented in jQuery or not?

Comment: i was looking for better solution for phones

Comment: You've been linked to a couple of angular-based implementations already. I don't see any value in switching to jQuery mid project, especially given that you don't seem to have any jQuery experience.